# create two separate observables that emit one after the other

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

(for use in writing a spec)

How can I create two observables with the second one that emits only after the first one completes ?

example:

```
myObservable1 = Observable.of(foo);
myObservable2 = Observable.of(bar);
```

`myObservable2` shoulf emit `bar` only after `myObservable1` emits `foo`

Comment: maybe this will help :) http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/combining-multiple-rxjs-streams-in-angular-2.0

Comment: OP has asked same question elsewhere, answer is here: Possible duplicate of [simulating two observables emiting successively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862851/simulating-two-observables-emiting-successively)

Answer (score 0):

You could use concatenation. The second won't start until the first completes:

```
const concatObservable = myObservable1.concat(myObservable2);
```