# simulating two observables emiting successively

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a component that has two properties that are observables

```
@Component({
})
export class MyComponent {
  observable1$;
  observable1$;

  ngOnInit() {
    Observable1$ = this.service.getObservable1();
    Observable2$ = this.service.getObservable2();
  }
}
```

I practice, `observable2$` will emit `bar` only after `observable1$` emits `foo`.

How can I write a test that simulates this?

If I write in my spec

```
 mockService.getObservable1.and.returnValue(Observable.of('foo'))

 mockService.getObservable2.and.returnValue(Observable.of('bar'))
```

than in my component, `observable1$` and `observable2$` won't be emiting successively...

How can I have `observable2$` emit after `observable1` in my spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need result from first for use in second you can use `switchMap()`:

```
Observable.of('foo').switchMap(foo => Observable.of(foo + 'bar'))
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res)) // 'foobar'
```

If you just want results of each when they arrive use [`forkJoin()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html):

```
Observable.forkJoin( Observable.of('foo'), Observable.of('bar'))
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res)) // 'foo', 'bar'
```